# Mocking the httpRequest of a mocked pageContext

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Is anybody aware of how to mock the following?

```
pageContext.getRequest().getParameter("par");// here I get a null pointer exception on getParameter
```

Is there any way to inject the httpRequest in the mock pageContext object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you need object to contain a particular value, you should read about **stubbing** in mockito.

Comment: Check out Mockito's spy functionality [in the API](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html) under chapter 13 "Spying on real objects"

Comment: Consider using spring-mock, which has a MockPageContext with a MockHttpServletRequest. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockPageContext.html

Answer (score 0):

stubbing can be used in chain. Following fragment shows the idea

```
    PageContext pageContext = mock(PageContext.class);
    HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
    when(request.getParameter("par")).thenReturn("what you want");
    when(pageContext.getRequest()).thenReturn(request);
```